# Cannot send HTML Emails

Tags: php, html, email, codeigniter

Well I'm trying to send a HTML email using gmail smtp from CI, and it seems to reject my emails when they have any amount of tables. No error is given, they just do not appear in my inbox.

If I send an email with light HTML and no tables, they go through. Anyone have any insight?

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '------@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '--------',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
 );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('myEmail', 'myName');
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('email')); 

    $this->email->subject('mySubject');
    $msg = $this->load->view('partials/email', '', true);
    $this->email->message($msg); 

    $this->email->send();`
```

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP double quotes evaluate variables and control characters (e.g. \n or \r), whereas single quotes do not. Also open the way to different interpretation = (equal sign). 
It not using TABLE is generation problem it is any tag with parameter ="value".

Make sure you have right string in single quotes, test this on basic A tag

The content of view 'partial/email' is the key

Comment: So you mean that the email can't contain any parameter="value" type html? would it work if those are single quotes or is the equals sign the issue?

Comment: No, it is allowed, however look closely in $msg string how it is built combination single, double quotes, and equal sign is the key - I did not face this problem - my former friend did - so I do not know too many details...

Comment: I've tried using either only double or only single quotes. I can't really remove the equals signs though....

Answer (score 0):

Include also the text/plain version of the message. Maybe it will go through, if you say that light html works